# Browser is stuck on loading the web page in vue.js 2 application but sometimes it load the same code successfully

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am facing problem in my vue.js 2 application. I am converting a bootstrap template to vue.js components. after breaking the code in components when i run a file it takes a lot of time to load the page and sometimes it load the same code successfully. I wonder if it is a problem on front side or server side. I am using localhost, webpack-simple.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get a good answer from the community, could you edit the question to add details of what you've tried already. Also, if you haven't already, I'd use Chrome DevTools (or your browser of choice) and look at the Network tab. When you refresh the page it will tell you how long the server took to respond, so you can decide whether that is the problem.

Comment: Sometimes it take few minutes and some time it load immediately

Comment: Can you show the actual html and vue code ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today I noticed vue running on 8086 port by netstat I killed node processes and run the server again vue runs on 8080 normally without any issues